# How to solve "$4\sqrt5$ is the same as which square root?"?

Tags: square-numbers

What is the right method for solving a problem like this:

”$4\sqrt{5}$ is the same as which square root?"

Possible answers are:

- $\sqrt{20}$
- $\sqrt{10}$
- $\sqrt{40}$
- $\sqrt{80}$

I have been informed that $\sqrt{80}$ is the right answer, but I do not understand why.

Comment: I now noticed that GeorgSalibe kindly adjusted the format of my question to how it should be used on this site. May I ask for a link or some other information about this procedure, so maybe I can do it correct from the beginning myself next time!

Comment: Hi! You would have to learn LaTeX, it's very easy. You can learn the basic mathematical operations in a day.

Comment: See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: About your other question, I simply could not understand why you cannot just use paper and pencil/pen. It is not that the multiplication table needs any computing power, since you know all the possible combinations and there are so few of them. I never intended any rudeness but I do intend that you seriously consider doing things without a computing device whenever reasonable. In fact, by the time you prepare a multiplication table on paper you probably would have memorized large chunks of it. Often the best way to get familiar with something is to do it all by yourself.

Comment: Generally we are in an agreement about this. And I notice that you never ment any rudness, so this is now OK for me. There are certain reasons why I, in this case, would like to use computer power. That does not matter now, but if you want to know the exact reason you can send me a personal message and I will explain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because $4=\sqrt{16}$. Then $\sqrt{16}\cdot \sqrt{5} = \cdots$

Comment: OK! So the point was to understand/remember that 4=√16, and then the head arithmetics will be something like: 1) 10*5=50 2) 6*5= 30, 3) 50+30=80 4) Put the result under the radical sign = √80. And thats it? OK! Thank you!

Comment: @BigSwede Yes. Until you have negative number under radical sign...

Comment: I see! I will come back if I must solve that kind of problem... =)

Answer (score 5):

I prefer this formulation, particularly for beginners:

$x=4 \times \sqrt{5} = \sqrt{16} \times \sqrt{5} = \sqrt{16\times5} = \sqrt{80}$

This is how I did it in my head when reading your question.

It's also good practice for solving proofs when you have to *appear* to go in the wrong direction for a moment (making $4$ lexically "larger", as $\sqrt{16}$) in order to bring terms together.

Comment: I like the formulation: "you have to appear to go in the wrong direction". Usually, the question is to simplify an expression and students are not aware that equality is a reflexive relation. So they are surprised when in some proofs we add and subtract the same quantity, whether it be $1 - 1$ or $-f(x+h)*f(x)+f(x+h)*f(x)$.

Comment: @BernardMassé: Yep, exactly. That was what I was (badly) trying to say. :) I was always quite good at those approaches in my youth, and for some reason found them very satisfying.

Answer (score 3):

$4\sqrt{5} = \sqrt{x} \Leftrightarrow \sqrt{4^25} = \sqrt{x}$

since $\sqrt{x}$ is injective $x = 4^25 = 80$

Comment: Thank you! This is maybe embarassing, but I do not understand the symbol "⇔". I do not understand the meaning of "injective" in this context either. Can you please explain?

Comment: $\Leftrightarrow$ means equivalent. An injective function takes different input values to different output values so if output is equal the input must also be equal.

Comment: OK, fine! I understand the part about "⇔". (I only partially understand the part about injective functions, but that does not matter at this Point!)So, thank you, we can stop there!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

use: $a\sqrt{b}=\dfrac{a}{|a|} \sqrt {a^2b}= \mbox{sign}(a)\sqrt {a^2b}$

---

Here $|a|$ is the absolute value of $a$, so that $\dfrac{a}{|a|}= 1$ if $a>0$ and $\dfrac{a}{|a|}= -1$ if $a<0$. This same result can be represented wit the function "sign (a)" that is simply the sign of $a$.

The use of this function is very important when we work with radicals because the square of a number is always positive, so, squaring $a$ we can forget that the basis of the square was negative.

In you case $a=4$, so  sign$(4)=+1$ and you have no problem writing:
$$
4 \sqrt{5}=\sqrt{16 \times 5}
$$

but if  you have , e.g. : $a=-4$ the correct result is:

$$
-4 \sqrt{5}=-\sqrt{16 \times 5}
$$

Comment: Thank you! Unfortenately I do not understand the meaning of "|a|". And not what "sign" means in the context. can you please explain?

Comment: I've added to my answer. I hope it's useful :)

Comment: It is now useful! I know very well what absolute value is, had just forgot the sign for it, the new thing was the function "sign (a)" which i did find most interesting! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

$x=4\sqrt 5\implies x^2=16\cdot 5=80\implies x=\sqrt{80}$

Comment: Thank you! I actually understand the answer, but not the meaning of, or general usage of, the symbols "x", "⟹" and "x 2" in this context. Can you please explain?

Comment: +1: This is the best approach, but (unfortunately, the most opaquely put. @BigSwede: The idea is to show that $$\left(4\sqrt5\right)^2=4^2\sqrt5^2=16\cdot5=80.$$ Hence, since $4\sqrt5$ is positive (why?), and since $4\sqrt5$ is a square root of $80$ ***by definition***, then $4\sqrt5=\sqrt{80}.$

Answer (score 1):

Notice, in general, for any two positive real numbers $a$ & $b$ $$a\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{a^2b}$$
Hence, we have $$4\sqrt{5}=\sqrt{(4)^2(5)}$$ $$=\sqrt{16\times 5}=\sqrt{80}$$ Yes $\sqrt{80}$ is right answer.

Comment: This answer I did understand! =) Thank you!